# When I'm using this below code in my project it gives error

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRAVESH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=shopping;Integrated Security=True");

    string a, b;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        a = Class1.GetRandomPassword(10).ToString();
        f1.SaveAs(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath+"./images/" + a + f1.FileName.ToString());
        b="images/" + a + f1.FileName.ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into product values('"+t1.Text+"','"+t2.Text+"','"+t3.Text+"','"+t4.Text+",'"+b.ToString()+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ///// Error Occured..
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

When I'm using this code in my project, It gives error:

> Error Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax
>   near 'images'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Can anyone please help me for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a single quote here: `'"+t4.Text+"`

All other arguments a properly wrapped, but this on is missing it's last quote.

The whole string concatenation is ugly, though. I'd suggest doing something else, maybe using `string.Format`, along the lines of:

```
string.Format("insert into product values('{0}', '{1}', ...)", t1.Text, t2.Text, etc etc);
```

Better yet, use sql paramaters